# Exception has occurred: AttributeError 'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm new at using python and I'm trying to make a web scraper for an internship

```
from typing import Container
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver


p1 = ["https://www.libris.ro/search?iv.q={}", "https://carturesti.ro/product/search/{}", "https://www.elefant.ro/search?SearchTerm={}&StockAvailability=true", "https://www.litera.ro/catalogsearch/result/?q{}", "https://www.librariadelfin.ro/?submitted=1&O=search&keywords{}&do_submit=1", "https://bookzone.ro/cautare?term={}", "https://www.librex.ro/search/{}/?q={}"]

#price_min = 1000000
#url_min, price_min

title = "percy jackson"
for x in p1:
    temp = x
    title = title.replace(" ", "+")
    url = temp.format(title)
    if url == "https://www.libris.ro/search?iv.q=" + title :
        **books = bs.find_all("div", class_="product-item-info imgdim-x")**
        for each_book in books:
            book_url = each_book.find("a")["href"]
            price = each_book.find("span", class_="price-wrapper")
            print(book_url)
            print(price)
```

and I'm getting this error for the text between the 2 asterisk :

```
Exception has occurred: AttributeError    
'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'
```

Comment: Please post the full traceback so that we can see the failing line.

Comment: This is invalid syntax:  `**books = bs.find_all("div", class_="product-item-info imgdim-x")**`

Comment: This isn't how `BeautifoulSoup` is used, you need to pass some content to it, e.g. `soup=bs(some_html, 'html.parser')` and then `soup.find_all(...)`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

After `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs`, `bs` is the class. You need to instantiate that class with data from the web site. In the code below, I've add a `requests` call to get the page and have built the beautifulsoup doc from there. You'll find some other errors in your code that need to be sorted out, but it will get you past this problem.

```
from typing import Container
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
from selenium import webdriver


p1 = ["https://www.libris.ro/search?iv.q={}", "https://carturesti.ro/product/search/{}", "https://www.elefant.ro/search?SearchTerm={}&StockAvailability=true", "https://www.litera.ro/catalogsearch/result/?q{}", "https://www.librariadelfin.ro/?submitted=1&O=search&keywords{}&do_submit=1", "https://bookzone.ro/cautare?term={}", "https://www.librex.ro/search/{}/?q={}"]

#price_min = 1000000
#url_min, price_min

title = "percy jackson"
for x in p1:
    temp = x
    title = title.replace(" ", "+")
    url = temp.format(title)
    if url == "https://www.libris.ro/search?iv.q=" + title :

        # THE FIX
        resp = requests.get(url)
        if not 200 <= resp.status_code < 299:
            print("failed", resp.status_code, url)
            continue
        doc = bs(resp.text, "html.parser")
        books = doc.find_all("div", class_="product-item-info imgdim-x")

        for each_book in books:
            book_url = each_book.find("a")["href"]
            price = each_book.find("span", class_="price-wrapper")
            print(book_url)
            print(price)
```

Comment: i've copied your code but now i'm getting another error 

Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'

   line 22, in <module>
    books = bs.find_all("div", class_="product-item-info imgdim-x")

Comment: Sounds like you are still running your old code. When I run this code, it goes further, processing some urls, but then gets `IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple` because of the format spec on one of your urls.

Comment: i made a change, i put in p1 just one url. now i don't get any error but it doesn't display anything

Comment: I think you should remove `if url == "https://www.libris.ro/search?iv.q=" + title :` ... that removes all but one of the urls from consideration.

Comment: yes, that was it:)))) 

but i still get this error
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute 'descendants'
  File "C:\Users\miron\OneDrive\Desktop\Code\scraper.py", line 21, in <module>
    books = bs.find_all("div", class_="product-item-info imgdim-x")